# Where is "Status Update History" in Database

Tags: database, t-sql, project-server, ms-project-server-2013

Does anyone out there know where the information for "Status Update History" in the Approval Center is located in the database?  In particular I am looking for the Status Flag (unpublished or published) for a given update.  I am trying to build a report off of this information and I am hoping someone has found this flag in the database.  I am using Project Server 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answered Post from Technet by Raushan_kumar](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/df85c49b-b449-446d-a3da-717bb3689382/status-update-history-in-database?forum=projectserver2010general#df85c49b-b449-446d-a3da-717bb3689382)

I am still interested in linking the actual hours approved to the query, but so far have been unsuccessful.

```
Status History related information are available in MSP_ASSIGNMENT_TRANSACTIONS table however Status Flag can be check by comparing WPROJ_LAST_PUB and ASSN_TRANS_SUBMIT_DATE fields.
```

SQL Query:

SELECT T.ASSN_TRANS_SUBMIT_DATE,  P.PROJ_NAME, A.TASK_NAME,

IS_PUBLISHED = CASE WHEN P.WPROJ_LAST_PUB > T.ASSN_TRANS_SUBMIT_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

FROM PUB.MSP_ASSIGNMENT_TRANSACTIONS T

LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB.MSP_ASSIGNMENTS_SAVED A ON T.ASSN_UID = A.ASSN_UID

LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB.MSP_PROJECTS P ON A.PROJ_UID = P.PROJ_UID